# Is there an easy way of downloading an old file version in GitKraken?

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

In GitKraken it is really easy to view files from earlier commits. Is there an easy way to save this earlier version - i.e. reverting the file to as it was in the chosen commit.

I've been doing it by copying and pasting the older content over the current version in a text editor.

Edit - maybe it's my lack of understanding of Git that's the problem.

Say I'm on version 100 of my app which is committed to GitHub and I want to restore just one file from version 95 but not revert the entire source code back to version 95. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

So - version 100 contains FileA, FileB, FileC and FileD but I want to retrieve **just** FileC from version 95.

Comment: By cherry picking the commit?

Comment: Yes, that's it - selecting certain files from a commit saving them to the current working folder.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is useful to other people, I have answered my own question.

Short answer is: using the GUI, no it isn't

But, by using `GitKraken`'s built in terminal it would be done like this:

```
git checkout [commit] [file]
```

Where `[commit]` is the commit id and `[file]` is the filename (supports wildcards)

e.g. `git checkout 160fcc Setup/*`

Would recover all files in the Setup folder and put them into the current working directory.